# What is wrong with this sum reduction in CUDA?

Tags: cuda

I am trying to perform a sum reduction over an array with 452591 elements, all of them set to 1, so the sum should be 452591.

I calculate the number of threads `nThreads` as the next power of 2, so it is 524288. At each iteration in the while cycle only the fist half of threads are supposed to work, adding at their i-th element the values of the other half. The addition only happens if there are an actual value within the array number of elements set on `nvalues`.

It works ok with 127, 1025, 1072 even 8271 elements. But not with 452591 and I can get why. The oputput for 452591 elements is 88064.

```
__global__ void sum_kernel(int nvalues, double nThreads, double *values)
{   int i = blockIdx.x * blockDim.x + threadIdx.x;
    while (nThreads > 1)
    {   int middle = nThreads / 2;
        int j = i + middle;
        if ( i < middle )
        {   if (j < nvalues )
            {   values[i] += values[j]; }
            else
            {   values[i] += 0;  }
        }
        __syncthreads();
        nThreads = middle;
    }
    if (i == 0)
        printf("T0 ------> %0.f \n", values[0] );
}
```

My guess is sometimes some theads add 0 when they shouldnt... or maybe am I getting the thread id wrongly?

For some more details, I calculate the next power of 2 as:

```
int expo = ceil(log(n) / log(base));
double next2Pow = (double) pow(base, expo)
```

The kernel is called with 1 dim blocks and `MAX_TPB = 1024` as:

`sum_kernel<<< ceil(next2Pow/MAX_TPB), MAX_TPB >>> (nvalues, next2Pow, values_device);`

Also, I have checked and the values in the device array are correct, since I can copy them to a host array, and get the sum correctly in the host.

But I want the kernel to work because of learning reasons.

Comment: I don't think you understand the nature of CUDA execution.  [Execution occurs by blocks](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#scalable-programming-model), so your reduction in global memory cannot work, because `__syncthreads()` only [synchronizes within a block](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#synchronization-functions).  If you want to  learn how to write a good parallel reduction, try [this](http://developer.download.nvidia.com/assets/cuda/files/reduction.pdf) and there is a cuda reduction sample code that goes along with it.

Comment: Instead of saying "cannot work" above, I probably should have said "is not guaranteed to work correctly for dataset sizes larger than 2048"

Comment: @RobertCrovella I am trying the example in the slide 35, but I get this error: no instance of function template "warpReduce" matches the argument list argument types are: (int [], unsigned int)

Comment: You may also want to check CUDA documentation on this site. There is not much there, but parallel reduction is present: http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/cuda/6566/parallel-reduction-e-g-how-to-sum-an-array

Comment: If you're having trouble implementing the code in the slides, you may want to refer to the [CUDA reduction sample code](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-samples/index.html#cuda-parallel-reduction), where it is already implemented.  To fix that particular issue, change this: `if (tid < 32) warpReduce(sdata, tid);`  to this: `if (tid < 32) warpReduce<blockSize>(sdata, tid);`

Answer (score 1):

> What is wrong with this sum reduction in CUDA?

In CUDA, the threads associated with a kernel launch (the *grid*) do not all execute together in lockstep.  CUDA [execution takes place by blocks](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#scalable-programming-model).

Your methodology, which attempts to cut the entire data set in half, would depend on having all the threads in the grid work together.  You may also be thinking that `__syncthreads()` synchronizes all threads in the grid (which would make this possible), but it does not.  It only [operates at the block level](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#synchronization-functions).

Rather than further dissect this, if you want to learn how to write a fast parallel reduction in CUDA, a good starting point would be [this treatment of it](http://developer.download.nvidia.com/assets/cuda/files/reduction.pdf) and there is a CUDA [sample code](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-samples/index.html#cuda-parallel-reduction) that provides a fully worked implementation of the various approaches covered in the presentation.